# How to remove the second repetition of combination in mySQL

Tags: mysql, update, unique-constraint

[image]

I have a datable like above and in that, unfortunately, repetitions occurs. How can I remove the repeated combination of 2nd, 3rd and 4th column and I need to make those three columns unique in combination.

Please help to write a query to do this, because there are 13000+ rows, so manual editing is hardly not possible.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*When finished, be sure to add this so dup rows won't recur:*

```
UNIQUE(exam, name, subject)
```

Plan A:

For that query (and assuming it does the desired task), it would help to have `INDEX(exam, name, subject, id)`.

Suggest you test it in a safe way...  Create another table and try it there.

```
CREATE TABLE test LIKE tablename;
ALTER TABLE test ADD INDEX(exam, name, subject, id);
INSERT INTO test
    SELECT * FROM tablename;
DELETE ...
...look at results...
```

If not right, `DROP TABLE test` and try again.
If looks good, then finish by moving the good result into place:

```
RENAME TABLE tablename TO old,
             test to tablename;
DROP TABLE old;
```

Plan B:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp
    SELECT MIN(id) AS id FROM tablename
        GROUP BY exam, name, subject;
DELETE tablename
    FROM tablename
    LEFT JOIN tmp  USING(id)
    WHERE tmp.id IS NULL;
```

(Again, you should probably test it on a copy.)

Plan C:  Even simpler, assuming you don't care what data you get for the extra columns:

```
CREATE TABLE new
    SELECT * FROM tablename
        GROUP BY exam, name, subject;
... check table `new` ...
RENAME TABLE tablename TO old,
             new to tablename;
DROP TABLE old;
```

That is, it won't necessarily give you the first `id`.  You may need a particular setting to turn off "only full group by" if you have a 'new' version of MySQL.

Comment: Jithin - which plan did you pick?  Did you experiment with all of them?  (Just curious.)

Comment: ALTER IGNORE TABLE foobar ADD UNIQUE (title, SID)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DELETE n1
    FROM tablename n1, tablename n2
    WHERE n1.id > n2.id
      AND n1.exam = n2.exam
      AND n1.name = n2.name
      AND n1.subject = n2.subject
```